# Android : Change color of blue shine (blue highlight) in List View

Tags: android, listview

I really want to change color of blue shine (blue highlight) was appeared when we attempt to pull at the top (or the end) in List View (many items at there).

Therefore, I want to change this color from blue to orange, guys.

http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/5609/28746577.jpg

p/s :

- I knew that blue color is default. (from ICS above)
- I add image to show, the yellow rectangle is the location appear the blue shine (or blue highlight)
- On Android 2.3.6 (HTC Device), the default color is orange.I knew that blue color is default. (from ICS above)

Thanks,

Comment: do u know what i say clearly? If u know, u can detail more for me to give u my code? I don't really know which code u need.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround, that worked for me:

http://evendanan.net/android/branding/2013/12/09/branding-edge-effect/

```
public static void brandGlowEffect(Context context, int brandColor) {

      //glow
      int glowDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
      Drawable androidGlow = context.getResources().getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
      androidGlow.setColorFilter(brandColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
      //edge
      int edgeDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_edge", "drawable", "android");
      Drawable androidEdge = context.getResources().getDrawable(edgeDrawableId);
      androidEdge.setColorFilter(brandColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

You have to invoke this method at OnCreate, right after setting the layout.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. You will find an explanation here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/i5a3uNN8jpg

```
public static void brandGlowEffect(Context context, int brandColor) {

      //glow
      int glowDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
      Drawable androidGlow = context.getResources().getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
      androidGlow.setColorFilter(brandColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
      //edge
      int edgeDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_edge", "drawable", "android");
      Drawable androidEdge = context.getResources().getDrawable(edgeDrawableId);
      androidEdge.setColorFilter(brandColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

You have to invoke this at OnCreate or OnCreateView.